# Run Superset as Service

Tags: daemon, apache-superset, python-daemon, start-stop-daemon

I have configured my superset in Virtual env want to run it as a service
I have tried using below config but its not working

```
[Unit]
Description=superset service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=superset
Group=superset
Environment=PATH=/home/ubuntu/code/superset:$PATH
Environment=PYTHONPATH=/var/superset/superset:$PYTHONPATH
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/code/superset/superset runserver 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Virtual Env folder is Superset

I get the below error

> /etc/init.d/superset: 1: /etc/init.d/superset: [Unit]: not found
> Usage: service < option > | --status-all | [ service_name [ command |
> --full-restart ] ] /etc/init.d/superset: 5: /etc/init.d/superset: [Service]: not found

Answer (score 4):

Actually the `superset runserver` is used for **development** mode and it is highly recommended other tools like **gunicorn** for **production**.
Anyway, the main problem is that **superset** path on the **virutalenv** is `$VENV_PATH/bin/superset` (in general the applications that treat like binary applications like *superset* or *airflow*, etc servers on this path: `$VENV_PATH/bin` and the easy way to find the path of any application on Linux systems is to use **which** command that in this case, you can use `which superset` to find the superset path ).

This is the superset service file that I use it on the production, hope to useful:

```
[Unit]
Description = Apache Superset Webserver Daemon
After = network.target

[Service]
PIDFile = /home/superset/superset-webserver.PIDFile
User = superset
Group = superset
Environment=SUPERSET_HOME=/home/superset
Environment=PYTHONPATH=/home/superset
WorkingDirectory = /home/superset
ExecStart =/home/superset/venv/bin/python3.7 /home/superset/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 8 --worker-class gevent  --bind 0.0.0.0:8888 --pid /home/superset/superset-webserver.PIDFile superset:app
ExecStop = /bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```